# Visual Studio 2017 Remote Debugger in Docker Windows Nanoserver Container Does not start

Tags: docker, visual-studio-debugging, nano-server

I copied the files from the Visual Studio 2017 Remote Debugger to a windows docker image running with nano server. After running MSVSMon.exe in headless mode with the proper arguments, nothing happens. There is no process running and no errors are generated in the application log. Why won't MSVSMon.exe start?

There are no instructions on the official site (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging#bkmk_configureService) on how to setup the program as a service non-interactively. So, how would I start this as a service since nano server has no ui?

```
PS C:\debug\vs_remotetools> .\msvsmon.exe /noauth /anyuser /silent /nostatus 
/noclrwarn /nosecuritywarn /nofirewallwarn
/nowowwarn /timeout:36000

PS C:\debug\vs_remotetools> get-process

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------
  0       5     1136       4752       2.20   1348   1 CExecSvc
  0       3     1704       2900       0.09   1888   1 cmd
  0       5      588       1936       7.19    916   1 csrss
  0       0        0          4                 0   0 Idle
  0      18     3532      10804       5.86    992   1 lsass
  0      42    52284      76844       9.50    596   1 powershell
  0      43    89044     115712      17.83   1452   1 powershell
  0      40    47668      72196      22.05   1704   1 powershell
  0       8     1312       5004       4.36    972   1 services
  0       2      284       1116       1.39    876   0 smss
  0       7     1488       5720       1.42    496   1 svchost
  0      12     1564       6104       2.53    780   1 svchost
  0      14    10436      14828       9.08   1036   1 svchost
  0      14     7900      16480      11.75   1068   1 svchost
  0       9     1948       6448       1.08   1136   1 svchost
  0      32     5864      15468       7.89   1160   1 svchost
  0      15     4356      13252       5.52   1324   1 svchost
  0       0      128        136      23.03      4   0 System
  0       7      808       4116       1.95    944   1 wininit
```

Comment: Is it similar to this issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36420337/running-visual-studio-remote-debugger-in-windows-container-docker-managed

Answer (score 1):

It could be bitness – Nano Server only supports 64bit binaries.

Information at these links might help:

https://github.com/Microsoft/NanoServerTools/blob/master/DevTools/ContainerDebug

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/nanoserver/2017/02/24/leverage-containers-to-test-and-debug-native-applications-on-nano-server/